# Добавление одного массива в конец другого

Tags: массивы, golang

Задача: Добавть один массив в другой

Как я хотел бы: Без использования циклов и рекурсии. Типы именно такие какие указаны в коде(`a :=[10]int{}`, `b:= []int{}`)

Как я могу: К сожалению тольк так и то же самое но циклом:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := [10]int{}
    b := []int{4, 5, 1, 8}
    i := len(a)
    j := len(b)
    fmt.Println(appendBtoA(a, b, i, j))
    //out: [0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 1 8]
}

func appendBtoA(a [10]int, b []int, i, j int) [10]int {
    i -= 1
    j -= 1
    if j >= 0 {
        a[i] = b[j]
        return appendBtoA(a, b, i, j)
    }
    return a
}
```

Но мне бы хотелось сделать через дополнительный срез указывающий на `a` и без использования циклов и рекурсий.

по логике:

```
// естественно не рабочий вариант. но нужно приблизительно так.
func appendBtoA2(a, b []int) []int {
    c := a[len(a)-len(b):] //здесь `c` если правильно понимаю, указывает на `a`
    c = b //здесь `c`, вроде как указывает на `b`. 
          //потому начальный массив не меняется.
          //но это все не точно а лишь мое дилетантское предположение
    return a
}
```

За основу желаемого решения взял механизм:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    a := [10]int{5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 8, 5}
    b := a[4:6]
    b[0] = 0
    b[1] = 0
    fmt.Println(a) //out: [5 4 6 7 0 0 4 5 8 5]
}
```

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Для начала следует понять что `[10]int` это массив, а `[]int` это слайс, который в памяти представляется совершенно иначе чем массив. И аргумент типа `[]int` вообще никак не может быть приведен к `[10]int` и наоборот.

Comment: @u_mulder, TC не собирается делать `append` или подобную операций. Он хочет `b` записать в конец `a`. А слайсы они или массивы - дело десятое.

Comment: Если бы они были слайсы - я сомневаюсь что были бы вообще проблемы. А вот массивы и слайсы уже другое.

Comment: Как это устроено без циклов можно посмотреть на примере функций `Insert` и `Replace` пакета `slices`: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.4:src/slices/slices.go;l=132

Comment: @u_mulder да, я понимаю, что слайсы и массивы не одно и то же.

Answer (score 4):

[`copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#copy) делает то что вам нужно:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    a := [10]int{}
    b := []int{4, 5, 1, 8}
    copy(a[len(a)-len(b):], b)
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", a)
}
```

> ```
> $ go run copy.go
> [0 0 0 0 0 0 4 5 1 8]
> ```

**P.S.** То, что `copy` - глобальная функция, намекает, что по другому это сделать трудно. Я бы предпочёл синтаксис `a[len(a)-len(b):] = b`, заимствованный из Питона. Но чего нет, того нет.

Answer (score 2):

C `append`-ом такой [вариант](https://go.dev/play/p/cgUhTgxur9z)

```
a := [10]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
b := []int{100, 200, 300}

pos := len(a) - len(b)
_ = append(a[pos:pos], b...)

fmt.Printf("%v; %v", a, b)
// [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 100 200 300]; [100 200 300]
```